# Migrating data from a One to Many to a HABTM relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, has-and-belongs-to-many, rails-migrations

I am new to rails and am working on updating a simple rails app. It currently has a one to many relationship between :categories to :galleries. I've changed both models to a HABTM relationship, and have created the join table migration.

Is there a way to set up a migration so that gallery_ids previously stored in the category table can be moved to the join table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this in your up migration.

```
Category.all.each do |cat|
 gallery = Gallery.find(cat.gallery_id)
 cat.galleries << gallery
 cat.save
end
```

You would want to destroy the association and add the gallery_id back in the down migration.

Comment: Is there anyway you could explain what this does exactly (sorry, I'm new to ruby and rails)

Comment: Sure, this iterates through the each of the categories. Then it will find the gallery from the gallery_id associated with each category (This was used for your one to many relationship). It will then add the gallery to an array the galleries array. Rails will create the necessary SQL for your habtm association behind the scenes. You will possibly want to handle if the gallery_id is nil in some cases, just dont update the array in that case.

Comment: added a condition to test if the id was blank, and it all worked great. Thankyouuu!!